Optimizing MySQL Queries for Generating Cartesian Products in Large Data Sets
I'm looking for efficient strategies to optimize a MySQL query that generates Cartesian products in scenarios involving large data sets. The specific use case involves pairing cast and crew members for each movie in a database, which can result in a very large number of combinations due to the size of the data involved.
The current query is as follows:
SELECT 
    m.title,
    pc.person_name AS cast_member,
    pr.person_name AS crew_member
FROM 
    movie m
JOIN 
    movie_cast mc ON m.movie_id = mc.movie_id
JOIN 
    person pc ON mc.person_id = pc.person_id
JOIN 
    movie_crew mcc ON m.movie_id = mcc.movie_id
JOIN 
    person pr ON mcc.person_id = pr.person_id;

Considering the following data:
  movies(movie_id, title): (1,'m1'), (2,'m2')
  person(person_id, name): (1, 'p1'), (2, 'p2'), (3, 'p3'), (4,'p4')
  movie_cast(movie_id, peson_id): (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,3)
  movie_crew(movie_id, peson_id): (1,1),(2,2), (2,4)

the result should be:
movie, cast, crew
m1      p1     p1
m1      p2     p1
m2      p1     p2
m2      p1     p4
m2      p3     p2
m2      p3     p4 

Please note that this query is used purely for research purposes and does not have a direct application. However, it could be applied to scenarios that require similar associations, such as retrieving movie titles, cast member names, and crew member names when individuals share the same surname.
I've considered using derived tables with the LATERAL clause to make this more efficient, but it led to inaccurate results. Are there other optimization techniques or approaches in MySQL that could improve the performance of this query?

Consider separating the bits that need to be cross joined (actor to crew )from the enrichment bits (names)

I need to cross join only the cast members and crew members that are related to the same movie.  I tried using the LATERAL clause with the movie ID as a correlated variable,  but it did not work out.

Main idea: if person is cast member and crew member related to the movie necessary join to one row for this movie (subquery pcc- person-cast-crew).
Person is on  booth(cast and crew) or one(cast/crew) side of query result.



movie_id
cast_id
crew_id




1
10
10


1
11
null


2
11
11


2
12
null


1
null
12


2
null
13



See example
select m.movie_id,title
  ,m1.person_name cast_member
  ,m2.person_name crew_member
from movie m
left join 
  (
  select movie_id
    ,min(case when pt='cast' then person_id end) cast_id
    ,min(case when pt='crew' then person_id end) crew_id
  from(
     select movie_id,person_id, 'cast' as pt from movie_cast
     union all
     select movie_id,person_id, 'crew' as pt from movie_crew
  )cast_and_crew
  group by movie_id,person_id
)pcc on pcc.movie_id=m.movie_id
left join person m1 on m1.person_id=pcc.cast_id
left join person m2 on m2.person_id=pcc.crew_id
order by m.movie_id,coalesce(m1.person_id,m2.person_id)

Fiddle here
OR
select m.movie_id,title
  ,case when pcc.cast_id is not null then p.person_name end cast_member
  ,case when pcc.crew_id is not null then p.person_name end crew_member
from movie m
left join 
  (
  select movie_id
    ,min(case when pt='cast' then person_id end) cast_id
    ,min(case when pt='crew' then person_id end) crew_id
  from(
    select movie_id,person_id, 'cast' as pt from movie_cast
    union all
    select movie_id,person_id, 'crew' as pt from movie_crew
   )cast_and_crew
  group by movie_id,person_id
)pcc on pcc.movie_id=m.movie_id
left join person p on p.person_id=coalesce(pcc.cast_id,pcc.crew_id)
order by m.movie_id,p.person_name

Demo
Test data
create table movie (movie_id int,title varchar(50));
create table movie_cast(movie_id int,person_id int);
create table movie_crew(movie_id int,person_id int);
create table person(person_id int,person_name varchar(50));
insert into movie values
 (1,'Movie 1')
,(2,'Movie 2')
;
insert into person values
 (10,'Carlson')
,(11,'Peterson')
,(12,'Henderson')
,(13,'Magnuson')
;
insert into movie_cast values
 (1,10)
,(1,11)
,(2,11)
,(2,12)
;
insert into movie_crew values
 (1,10)
,(1,12)
,(2,11)
,(2,13)
;


I've tested the query, and it performs efficiently, which is impressive. However, it doesn't return the desired product between cast members and crew members as expected. What I'm looking for is to associate each cast member with every crew member, essentially creating all possible pairs between the two groups that are connected by the same movie. I understand this might seem somewhat non-standard, but my goal is to explore if such a task can be achieved efficiently within the database context. Any insights or suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated

So, you can show sample data and desired result?

sure, I have included a full example.

CREATE TABLE movie_cast (
    -- no id
    movie_id ...,
    person_id ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(movie_id, person_id),
    INDEX(person_id, movie_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

